# jQuery validate plugin fails to ignore checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an AJAX form where I have tons of text fields. These text fields validate just fine with no issues however as soon as I add a checkbox via MVC framework(resulting HTML code bellow).

```
<input id="NotifyLocation" class="check-box" type="checkbox" value="true"
 name="NotifyLocation" data-val-required="The NotifyLocation field is required." 
 data-val="true" checked="checked"></input>
```

jQuery plugin throws an error from within this code inside of the plguin.

```
attributeRules: function(element) {
    var rules = {};
    var $element = $(element);

    for (var method in $.validator.methods) {
        var value;
        // If .prop exists (jQuery >= 1.6), use it to get true/false for required
        if (method === 'required' && typeof $.fn.prop === 'function') {
            value = $element.prop(method);
        } else {
            value = $element.attr(method);
        }
        if (value) {
            rules[method] = value;
       //ERROR is thrown on the next line
        } else if ($element[0].getAttribute("type") === method) {
            rules[method] = true;
        }
    }

    // maxlength may be returned as -1, 2147483647 (IE) and 524288 (safari) for text inputs
    if (rules.maxlength && /-1|2147483647|524288/.test(rules.maxlength)) {
        delete rules.maxlength;
    }

    return rules;
}
```

The error message is "**TypeError: $element[0] is undefined**". I have tried adding the following code to force jQuery to ignore the checkbox in my ready method

```
 $("#frmAjaxLocationUpdater").validate({
        ignore: "#NotifyLocation *"
    });
```

but still I get the same error within jQuery validation plugin. I have tried to add rules by class still same issue. According to numerous posts this should work but it doesn't.

Any ideas what is going on ? What can cause this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show demo of error on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com
And your code not plugin code..

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by my code. My code is   $("#frmAjaxLocationUpdater").validate({
        ignore: "#NotifyLocation *"
    });

Comment: Try `ignore: "#NotifyLocation"`. Adding `*` only matches descendants, not the element itself.

Comment: Same thing same error "TypeError: $element[0] is undefined"

Comment: Does your MVC framework actually create potentially invalid HTML?  `<input></input>` should be a self-closing element, `<input/>`

Comment: Nope that's valid unconventional but valid.

Comment: Sure seems like invalid HTML to me, so I ran `<input></input>` through the W3C Validator using both HTML 4.01 and HTML 5 specs.  _"Error:  end tag for element "INPUT" which is not open"_ and _"Stray end tag input"_.  Please explain where it's valid.

Comment: Any browser will support <input></input>

Comment: Browsers support a lot of things.  Does not mean they are valid or that they will always be supported.  I'm curious about which framework outputs invalid HTML.

Comment: Ok, back to my original question. HTML has nothing to do with the issue at hand. I think the issue is that .NET MVC framework puts a data-val="true" attribute on the tag this forces jQuery to validate. Validation plugin seems unable to handle it.

Comment: Ok, figured it out as I said in my previous post the issue is related to data-val="true" attribute. I have added a piece of code `document.getElementById("NotifyLocation").setAttribute("data-val","false") ;` which sets it to false and my problem went away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of JavaScript code that solved my issue

```
document.getElementById("NotifyLocation").setAttribute("data-val","false") ;
```